# Concating string inside expression in expression in angular 7

Tags: angular

Hi I am trying to concatenate two string values inside expression but its not working please find the code below

```
<ng-template #genericDropDown let-Data="data" let-WidgetID="widgetID" let-Title="title" let-Placeholder="placeholder">
 <div class="select-wrap input-group">
   **<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{[Placeholder]==='Common.Benefit_Type' ? [Placeholder| translate] + '...': [ Placeholder| translate]}}" />**
   <div class="input-group-btn">
     <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg"> <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
         role="button" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="icon icon-dropdown-icon"></span></span>
       <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
         <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
           <h5>{{ Title|translate }}</h5>
           <div class="dropdownoverflow">
             <span class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let element of Data">
               <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 pull-left col-lg-1 col-md-1 pull-left marginRT10 nopadding">
                 <input type="checkbox" id="{{ WidgetID + element.id + element.key }}" value="{{ element.id }}"
                   (change)="onBenefitTypeChange(WidgetID,$event, element)" />
                 <label for="{{ WidgetID + element.id + element.key }}"></label>
               </div>
               {{ element.key }}
             </span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 nopadding">
             <button (click)="filterByBenefitType(WidgetID)" type="submit"
               class="btn btn-submit pull-right" translate='Common.Submit'></button>
             <button (click)="clearFilterOfBenefitType(WidgetID)" type="button"
               class="btn btn-clear pull-right" translate="Common.Clear"></button>
           </div>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</ng-template>
```

I am trying to evaluate expression inside an expression and in the value I am trying to concatenate '...' with the placeholder value.

Its the first input box from the top in the code

It looks fairly simple but for some reason it is not working, I am trying to resolve it for the last 2 hours but couldn't resolve it.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @Edric Sorry just edited it, thanx

Comment: Why are you using square brackets in-between the `Placeholder` variable in the `placeholder` attribute? And I suggest that you should probably move this logic to a method instead as it may not be easily readable.

Comment: @edric it is an expression , if we want to evaluate expression in expression then this is the way right? Or do u have any other way then please let me know it may fix my issue

Comment: No, it's not - chances are the Angular compiler probably interprets that the `[Placeholder]` portion is an array and not an expression.

Comment: @Edric but its working fine, its just not adding the ... at the end

Comment: @Edric you were right, I think it was considering it as array, I made changes in my code to this   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{(Placeholder)==='Common.Benefit_Type' ? (Placeholder| translate) + '...': (Placeholder| translate)}}" />    and it worked.   Thank you

Comment: You should probably self-answer your question with the changes you've made to your code such that it can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Edric said i think due to square brackets angular was considering it as array thats why it was not concatenating the string.

So I changed my code to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{(Placeholder)==='Common.Benefit_Type' ? (Placeholder| translate) + '...': (Placeholder| translate)}}" />
```

And it worked.